# How to create a scatter plot by category and order the values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a data table and I want to produce a scatter plot with the year of an activity on the x-axis, school class on the y-axis, and the theme of cultural activities as a category.

This is what my data looks like:

| id | année suivi | thematique itinéraire | segpa | classe | ordre classe | couleur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-2023 | Spectacle vivant | False | 6ème | 6 - 6ème | #cf84c4 |
| 2 | 2022-2023 | Spectacle vivant | True | 4ème | 4 - 4ème | #cf84c4 |
| 3 | 2022-2023 | Education aux médias et à l'information | False | 5ème | 5 - 5ème | #00b6cf |
| 4 | 2022-2023 | Education aux médias et à l'information | False | 4ème | 4 - 4ème | #00b6cf |
| 5 | 2019-2020 | Livres et lecture | False | 6ème | 6 - 6ème | #bd9f38 |
| 6 | 2022-2023 | Spectacle vivant | True | 4ème | 4 - 4ème | #cf84c4 |
| 7 | 2022-2023 | Spectacle vivant | False | 6ème | 6 - 6ème | #cf84c4 |
| 8 | 2019-2020 | Spectacle vivant | False | 6ème | 6 - 6ème | #cf84c4 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I have many problems. I couldn't figure how to order the x-and y-axes. I also couldn't figure how to categorize my data. I don't know how to size the point with the count of value or add a legend.

The values in x are interval of years.

The best I could do:

[image: Actual situation]

In python, I tried this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# ajout d'une colonne couleur au soustableau
soustableau['couleur'] = soustableau['thematique itinéraire'].map({'Patrimoine':'#51b76a', 
                                                                   'Arts visuels':'#889cf0', 
                                                                   'Livres et lecture':'#bd9f38', 
                                                                   'Culture scientifique':'#e58370',
                                                                   'Spectacle vivant':'#cf84c4',
                                                                   '''Education aux médias et à l'information''':'#00b6cf' })

# liste des périodes ordonnées
ordre_annee = ['2019-2020','2020-2021','2021-2022','2022-2023']

# problème : ordonner l'axe des x !!
# faire une légende

viz = soustableau.plot(
   x='année suivi', 
   y='ordre classe', 
   c = 'couleur',
   kind='scatter',
   #label='couleur',
   legend=True,
   figsize=(15, 10),
   fontsize=15, 
   title='itinéraire des classes par année scolaire'
   
)

viz.margins(0.1)

plt.show()
```

Seems like seaborn is the library I should use, but I couldn't find a proper example. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) to ensure a custom sorted order, and compute a [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) for the size:

```
df['année suivi'] = pd.Categorical(df['année suivi'])

order = ['CM2', '6ème', '5ème', '4ème', '3ème', '2nde', '1ère']
df['classe'] = pd.Categorical(df['classe'], categories=order, ordered=True)

(df.groupby(['année suivi', 'classe', 'couleur'], as_index=False).size()
   .assign(size=lambda d: d['size']*500)
   .plot(x='année suivi', 
         y='classe', 
         c='couleur',
         kind='scatter',
         s='size',
         legend=True,
         #figsize=(15, 10),
         fontsize=15, 
         title='itinéraire des classes par année scolaire'
   )
)
```

*NB. the logic was not fully clear, so I grouped by year/class/color, but use whichever groups make sense, for instance "thematique itinéraire" could be used.*

Output:

[image]

A different example with [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.scatterplot(df.groupby(['année suivi', 'classe', 'thematique itinéraire'],
                           as_index=False).size(),
                x='année suivi', y='classe',
                hue='thematique itinéraire', size='size',
                style='thematique itinéraire'
                )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Just needed to add



`soustableau['année suivi'] =  soustableau['année suivi'].astype("category")
soustableau['classe'] =  soustableau['classe'].astype("category")
`

to translate the datas in category types.

Seaborn seems to be way simplier to use. 

Anyway, once again, thanks.